# Hooking up MS SQL Server databae with AWS Cognito for Authentication

Tags: sql-server, amazon-cognito, asp.net-membership

I have been using `ASPNet Membership` in `MSSQL Server` for my authentication/authorization purposes, for one of the project i want to use `AWS Cognito` for the Authentication and generating an `id token` for other applications to consume and authenticate `(SSO)`.

I want to connect my SQL database to the AWS Cognito user pool, so that when user attempts to login it will automatically check the authenticity of the user against my MS Sql database.

Can anyone tell me how i could hookup/connect my MS SQL Database to AWS Cognito, please note my MS SQL Server is behind the VPN.